# Load csv.gz file from google storage to bigquery using python

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I want to load csv.gz file from storage to bigquery. Right now I using below code, but I am not sure if it is efficient way to load data to bigquery.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import storage
import pandas_gbq as gbq
client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(service_account)
bucket = client.get_bucket("bucketname")
blob = storage.blob.Blob("""somefile.csv.gz""", bucket)
content = blob.download_as_string()
df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(content), delimiter=',', quotechar='"', low_memory=False)
df = df.astype(str)
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("|", "")
df["dateinsert"] = pd.datetime.now()
gbq.to_gbq(df, 'desttable',
           'projectid',
           chunksize=None,
           if_exists='append'
           )
```

Please assist me to write this code in efficient way

Comment: Yes, there is easier, but for the best answer, I need more details. What do you want to achieve? What are your constraint? For example, why are you using the `dateInsert`? is the day granularity is enough or your need more precision? How big are your files? Why do you replace | ? (...) Provide as detail as you can.

Comment: My file contains more than 150 columns, and column names contains some characters like  {,}, [,], | etc. So I want to replace the special characters in the column so bigquery will accept. Date Insert column just to know the loading time. It is very big file contains 1 million rows

Comment: Why the special character are problematic in BigQuery? Are they present in "numeric field" and this special character for the field to be a string ?

Comment: Hi Guilaume, special character are ther in csv headers, so i just replacing then with '_' , so bigquery can accept as column.

Answer (score 1):

I propose you this process:

- Perform a [load job into bigquery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv)

  - Add the schema, *yes 150 column is boring...*
  - Add skip leading row option for skipping the header `job_config.skip_leading_rows = 1`
  - Name your table like this `<dataset>.<tableBaseName>_<Datetime>` The date time must be a string format compliant with BigQuery table name. For example `YYYYMMDDHHMM`

When you query your data, you can query a subset of table, and inject the table name in the query result, like this:

```
SELECT *,(SELECT table_id
      FROM `<project>.<dataset>.__TABLES_SUMMARY__`
      WHERE table_id LIKE '<tableBaseName>%') FROM `<project>.<dataset>.<tableBaseName>*`
```

Of course, you can raffine the * with the year, month, day,...

I think, I meet all your requirements. Comment if something goes wrong